# How to make multi-threaded requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multithreading

I have written this code:

```
import requests
redfile = open('/root/Desktop/23/1.txt','r')
url = input('Type url :' )

for x in redfile:
    req = requests.get(url + '/' + x.rstrip())
    if req.status_code == 200:
        print('this page' + url + '/' + x +'is avable')
        f = open('/root/Desktop/23/2.txt','a')
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(url+'/'+x)
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

Now I need a make the requests multi-threaded.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a thread pool and the `concurrent.futures` module is the most flexible:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# worker thread to process one url:
def proccess_url(url, session):
    r = session.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('this page' + url + ' is avable')
        with open('/root/Desktop/23/2.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(url)
            f.write('\n')


url = input('Type url: ' )
#create all the urls:
with open('/root/Desktop/23/1.txt','r') as redfile:
    urls = [url + '/' + x.rstrip() for x in redfile]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
    session = requests.Session()
    futures = [executor.submit(process_url, url, session) for url in urls]
    for future in futures:
        future.result() # wait for each thread to end; worker thread implicitly returns None
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you search for:

```
import requests
import threading


def thread(urls):
    while True:
        if len(urls) < 1:
            break
        url = urls.pop()
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.ok:
            print('this page' + url  + 'is avable')
            with open('/root/Desktop/23/2.txt','a') as f:
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(url)
                f.write('\n')

urls = []
baseurl = input('Type url :' )
threads = []
for line in open('/root/Desktop/23/1.txt'):
    urls.append(baseurl + '/' + line.rstrip())
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(urls,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print('Done')
```

Using the threading module like this make your script multi threaded. This script will have 10 threads:

```
for i in range(10):
```

Comment: So rather than passing to each thread a single URL, you are passing to all of the threads all of the URLs and that's because you are using a fixed number of threads *without* using one of the standard thread pooling mechanisms, which is what this solution calls for. In essence you are creating your own thread pooling mechanism. But I don't know why you just didn't use the  `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`, which has the interface of `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` but uses threads.

Comment: Ahh.. Yes it works fine and do the job fast but not to fast in most of the cases. Much more then 10 threads tend to make the site block you.

Comment: The issue is not the number of threads. The point I am questioning is why you chose not to use the standard thread pooling mechanism that comes with Python and instead "reinvented the wheel" as you have done. If you used, for example, the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` you can specify `max_workers=10` or whatever size pool you want, and when a thread is finished processing one URL it will then be re-used to process the next URL.

Comment: I used the threading module because I'm more familiar with it then concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor and it does what TS asked for. But you have also provided a good solution to TS question